# Creating new AD users and adding them to multiple groups from CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have been given the task of creating a school's worth of users (UK Secondary).  The PS to create the users from a CSV, what I need to do is add the newly created users to various groups at the same time.

The code I am using is as follows

```
$DCName = '<DC FQDN>'

Import-Csv -Path "D:\Import.csv" |

ForEach-Object {
    $Displayname = $_.'FirstName' + " " + $_.'LastName'
    $UPN = $_.'UPN'
    $GroupName = $_.'GroupName'
    $Prop = @{
        Name = $Displayname
        DisplayName = $_.'FirstName' + " " + $_.'LastName'
        GivenName = $_.'FirstName' 
        Surname = $_.'LastName' 
        UserPrincipalName = $UPN 
        EmailAddress = $UPN 
        SamAccountName = $_.'SAM' 
        AccountPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString $_.'Password' -AsPlainText -Force) 
        Enabled = $true 
        Path = $_.'OU' 
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false 
        Title = $_.'JobTitle' 
        StreetAddress = $_.'Street' 
        City = $_.'Town' 
        State = $_.'County'
        PostalCode = $_.'PostCode' 
        OfficePhone = $_.'Telephone' 
        Company = $_.'Company' 
        Department = $_.'Department' 
        HomeDrive = $_.'HomeDrive' 
        HomeDirectory = $_.'Home-Directory' 
        OtherAttributes = @{
            'extensionAttribute1'= $_.'ExtendedAttribute1'; 
            'extensionAttribute2'= $_.'ExtendedAttribute2'; 
            'extensionAttribute14'= $_.'ExtendedAttribute14'; 
            'extensionAttribute15'= $_.'ExtendedAttribute15'; 
            'proxyAddresses' = "SMTP:" + $UPN;} 
        Server = $DCName

        }

         New-ADUser @prop

         Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -Members $_.'SAM'

}
```

The user gets created with all properties correctly set.  It fails with the following error

```
Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'Test.User' under: 'DC=AD,DC=example,DC=uk'.
At C:\Scripts\NewUserFromCSV2.ps1:47 char:10
+          Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -Members $_.'SAM'
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Test.USer:ADPrincipal) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

It looks like the Add-ADGroupMember command can't find the user that has just been created, however, if that is the case I don't understand why.

Also at the moment, my CSV has only one group in the 'GroupName', what would be the best way to add the user to multiple groups? e.g. School-All-Staff, Teaching-Staff, Science-Teachers etc.

Thanks in advance for any help received.

Comment: It might well be a replication issue, that your DC isn't aware of the new user yet. You can add a manual delay to allow for this by adding `Start-Sleep -s 30` between the two commands...

Comment: That would mean that each user would take at least 30 seconds to complete.  There are nearly 200 staff and 1500 students - meaning it would take over 14 hours to complete.

Comment: would adding the server switch to the Add-ADGroupMember command help?

Comment: That was a suggestion for fault finding, to see if it's code or replication. Pointing both commands to the same Server would solve this, but you also put all the load on a single server. If your Domain is setup to deal with this that's fine.

Comment: @JamesC You're not doing this every night, right? If it's only a one-time thing for a new AD domain that's not live yet, what's 14 hours matter? 'Cause if this runs more often, it's kind of scary bad that you have plain-text passwords there. In fact, it's still kind of scary you have this but don't set "ChangePasswordAtLogon". And if it's not more often, you can just start it before leaving for the night.

Comment: Also: just checked my own code for my production system, and my Add-ADGroupMember command looks virtually identical. The difference is my create user and group member ship parts are in separate scripts. I have one script running nightly to create new users, and a separate script scheduled a few minutes later to sync group memberships for faculty and students based on data in our student information system. So you could do something like that: just create the users (all of them), wait a few minutes, and then add all of the group memberships. Everything finishes in a reasonable time period.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn you've tagged the wrong James ;)

Comment: @JamesC. Lol, oops. At least he should still see the response to his own question.

Comment: Thanks for your responses - @JamesC

Comment: Thanks for your responses - @JamesC it was a replication issue, I did add the server switch to both commands and it worked - server load isn't high enough to cause issues. (pressed enter too soon the first time)

Comment: @Joel Coehoom - we aren't doing this every night, it's a relatively infrequent operation as we add new schools to the Multi-academy Trust.

Comment: I still question using plain-text passwords here. If you're gonna accept that, you need to require them to change right after.

Answer (score 1):

As it's a bulk operation, I would just split the user creation from the group membership.

Create all the users first, then add them to the groups:

```
$DCName = '<DC FQDN>'
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "D:\Import.csv"

$Users | ForEach-Object {
    $Displayname = $_.'FirstName' + " " + $_.'LastName'
    $UPN = $_.'UPN'

    $Prop = @{
        ## properties as per original code ##
    }

    New-ADUser @prop
}

$Users | ForEach-Object {
    $GroupName = $_.'GroupName'
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -Members $_.'SAM'    
}
```

---

The to add the users to multiple groups:

If you've got a semicolon separated list of the groups in `GroupName` eg

```
School-All-Staff;Teaching-Staff;Science-Teachers
```

`Split` will convert this to an array then you can loop through them:

```
$_.'GroupName' -split ';' | ForEach-Object {
    Add-ADGroupMember $_ –Member $user.'SAM'
}
```

(edit: updated to semicolon as you have a csv source)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working as a combined script in the end and added in error checking for pre-existing users, existing staff often move to the new school that is being added to the Trust prior to its addition to our AD and get included in the list of users to create.

Also added log file creation to record newly created users and list those whose SAMAccount name already exists so we can check to see if the user does need creating or if they need moving from another School OU.

This is my final code:

```
#Get deafult variables to tidy up created variables at the end
$ExistingVariables = Get-Variable | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

#New User Code Starts Here>

#Variables not set by CSV

#Set DC name to update - prevents errors due to replication delay
$DCName = '<DC FQDN>'

#Create log files
"Users Exist in AD" | Out-File -FilePath "D:\Logs\ExistingUsers-$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd).txt" -Append
"New Users Created" | Out-File -FilePath "D:\Logs\NewUsers-$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd).txt" -Append

#Specify path and file to import
Import-Csv -Path "D:\Import.csv" |

#Iterate through each row in the CSV
ForEach-Object {

    #Set per object variables from fields in the CSV
    $DisplayName = $_.'FirstName' + " " + $_.'LastName'
    $UPN = $_.'UPN'
    $GroupName1 = $_.'GroupName1'
    $GroupName2 = $_.'GroupName2'
    $GroupName3 = $_.'GroupName3'
    $GroupName4 = $_.'GroupName4'
    $SAM = $_.'SAM'
    $Password = $_.'Password'
    $SAMTest = Get-ADUser -Filter {(sAMAccountName -eq $SAM)} -Server $DCName

    #Splatting Hash Table holds all user attribute properties set in the CSV
    $Prop = @{
        Name = $DisplayName
        DisplayName = $DisplayName
        GivenName = $_.'FirstName' 
        Surname = $_.'LastName' 
        UserPrincipalName = $UPN 
        EmailAddress = $UPN 
        SamAccountName = $_.'SAM' 
        AccountPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString $_.'Password' -AsPlainText -Force) 
        Enabled = $true 
        Path = $_.'OU' 
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false 
        Title = $_.'JobTitle' 
        StreetAddress = $_.'Street' 
        City = $_.'Town' 
        State = $_.'County'
        PostalCode = $_.'PostCode' 
        OfficePhone = $_.'Telephone' 
        Company = $_.'Company' 
        Department = $_.'Department' 
        OtherAttributes = @{
            'extensionAttribute1'= $_.'ExtendedAttribute1'; 
            'extensionAttribute2'= $_.'ExtendedAttribute2'; 
            'extensionAttribute14'= $_.'ExtendedAttribute14'; 
            'extensionAttribute15'= $_.'ExtendedAttribute15'; 
            'proxyAddresses' = "SMTP:" + $UPN;} 
        Server = $DCName

        }


    #Check if SAMAccount name exists in AD and skip existing users
    if ($SAMTest -ne $Null)
        {
        #Get UPN property of the pre-existing user
        $Exist = Get-ADUser -Filter {(sAMAccountName -eq $SAM)} -Properties 'userprincipalname'

        #write UPN value to variable
        $ExistUPN = $Exist.userprincipalname

        #Update log of pre-existing users
        "$DisplayName exists with email $ExistUPN" | Out-File -FilePath "D:\Logs\ExistingUsers-$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd).txt" -Append

        #Write to screen
        Write-Host "$DisplayName already exists in AD" -ForegroundColor Red

        }
    else
        {
        #Create new user with the attribute properties collected above
        New-ADUser @prop

        #Check if group fields in CSV were populated, if true add user to group, if false skip                  
        if ($_.'GroupName1'){Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.'GroupName1' -Members $_.'SAM' -Server $DCName}

        if ($_.'GroupName2'){Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.'GroupName2' -Members $_.'SAM' -Server $DCName}

        if ($_.'GroupName3'){Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.'GroupName3' -Members $_.'SAM' -Server $DCName}

        if ($_.'GroupName4'){Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.'GroupName4' -Members $_.'SAM' -Server $DCName} 

        #Update New user log 
        "$UPN" | Out-File -FilePath "D:\Logs\NewUsers-$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd).txt" -Append

        #Write to screen
        Write-Host "User $SAM created at $((Get-Date).ToString('hh:mm'))" -ForegroundColor Green

        }
}

#End Of New User Code

#Remove variables set by script - keeps PS memory space tidy
$NewVariables = Get-Variable | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Where-Object {$ExistingVariables -notcontains $_ -and $_ -ne "ExistingVariables"}
if ($NewVariables)
    {
    Write-Host "Removing the following variables:`n`n$NewVariables"
    Remove-Variable $NewVariables
    }
else
    {
    Write-Host "No new variables to remove!"
    }
```

I used the bit about clearing up variables because the values seemed to persist if the PowerShell session remained open and it was causing odd things to happen.  I also removed the home drive attributes because the file server specified hasn't been implemented yet but management still wants the users in AD now.

For reference my import.csv looks like this

```
FirstName,LastName,UPN,SAM,Password,OU,JobTitle,Street,Town,County,PostCode,Telephone,Company,Department,ExtendedAttribute1,ExtendedAttribute2,ExtendedAttribute14,ExtendedAttribute15,GroupName1,GroupName2,GroupName3,GroupName4
Test,User,Test.Users@domain.uk,Test.User,,"OU=Admin Staff,OU=User Resources,OU=School,OU=Trust Schools,DC=AD,DC=Trust,DC=org",,Street Name,TownName,County,AA11 1AA,116123,Name Of School,Name Of Trust,,Staff,,,AllStaffGroup,AdminStaffGroup,SpecialPermissionsGroup,Group4
```